# How to hide a div with jquery or alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap_all">
<header id="header" class="header_color light_bg_color mobile_drop_down" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" itemscope="itemscope" role="banner">
<div id="overlay-2"></div>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay-2 {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
opacity: 0.85;  
z-index: 10;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$('.custom_class_1').click(function()    {
    $('#overlay-2').fadeIn(300);
    });
```

I want to toggle the visibility of #overlay-2 when I click on my button ".custom_class_1"

How can I do this? 
Not sure if `visibility: hidden`is the route to go in the css. But I do want it hidden on page load as it would cover the entire screen with a dark overlay.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: display:none instead of visibility

Comment: or call hide() before fadeIn(): $('#overlay-2').hide().fadeIn(300);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.custom_class_1').click(function()    {
       $('#overlay-2').toggle();
    });
```

And in your main css, as others have suggested you should use `Display: none` in place of `Visibility: hidden`

Comment: The animation signature of `toggle` hasn't been removed.

Comment: Oh ok, that was the only part they removed then?

Comment: No, I mean, `.toggle()` to toggle display (with and without animation) has been kept, only the `.toggle(function[, function...])` to assign click handlers has been removed (which can be restored with the Migrate plugin).

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @JustinM Thanks for that it looks like it's on the right track. Unfortunately I'm pretty new to Jquery, and am not sure where to take it with the toggle stuff. Can you help me out with more of the code if you have time, or reference a link where I can learn to do it :)

Comment: If I understood your use case correctly the code I have provided should be enough with what you already have to get it to work. All toggle does is if the display style on the element is set to none, it will either set it to block or inline-block, and if it is set to block or inline-block it will set it to none. Effectively toggling the visibility; here is a link to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: hmm not sure why then.

Comment: Well, I guess I should make sure "use custom JS" is turned on in the plugin I'm using!!! HAHAHA, there's always one more button!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery then use the .hide() method:

$("#overlay-2").hide();

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Using hide means you will need to track the state so that if it is hidden you call .show(); .toggle() handles this for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS solution - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/eD6e4/1/)

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='inputstyle'></input>

<div class='centerme'>
<label for="inputstyle"><span>Click Me</span></label>
</div>

<div class='hideme'></div>
```

CSS

```
.centerme {
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.hideme {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.clickme:active > .hideme {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hideme {
   display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + div label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

From [THIS](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) excellent page.